# Mysql Between function not working in join

Tags: mysql

I have a query where is first check the LIKE in the productpost table with the value where the propertyid is 1 or 4 then,(upto this it work perfectly)  AND but the next part where propertyid is 3 and has value 0 to 50 (this part of query brings all the results in database the result, whereas it should have brought only the ones that has value 0 to 50 in propertyid 3

productpost table:
[image: productpost table]

I have tried with many things instead of between but it does not work, everything is ok before the last part of the code

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) as `num` FROM product a INNER JOIN customer b ON a.userid=b.cid INNER JOIN productcategory c ON a.id=c.id INNER JOIN productpost d ON a.adid=d.adid WHERE a.verif=1 AND c.cattype=1 AND (d.value LIKE '%a%') AND (d.propertyid in (1,4)) AND (d.propertyid=3 AND d.value BETWEEN 0 AND 50)
```

Everything works perfectly but this part, but the addition of this part starts to give wrong results

```
(d.propertyid=3 AND d.value BETWEEN 0 AND 50)
```

EXAMPLE :
If I give an example it would be that if there are 4 "adid" and 3 of them has LIKE '%a%' in value in propertyid 1 and 4, and among those three, 2 of them has value 0 to 50 in propertid 3, so in first condition it filter out three and in the next condition it filters value between 0 to 50 and at the end shows two "adid".

THE MCRE CODE THAT I WANT BUT IS NOT WORKING :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(adid) FROM productpost WHERE (value LIKE '%a%' AND (propertyid in (1,4)) AND (SELECT * FROM productpost WHERE propertyid=3 AND value BETWEEN 501 AND 510)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `adcategory` (
  `id` int(99) NOT NULL,
  `adid` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `cattype` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `catvalue` varchar(99) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `adcategory` (`id`, `adid`, `cattype`, `catvalue`) VALUES
(15, 'a98e7e97e2', '1', '1'),
(16, 'a98e7e97e2', '2', '2'),
(17, 'ad129031b6', '1', '1'),
(18, 'ad129031b6', '2', '2'),
(19, '0906c4d03d', '1', '1'),
(20, '0906c4d03d', '2', '2'),
(21, '09120c53c7', '1', '1'),
(22, '09120c53c7', '2', '2'),
(23, '09b8369032', '1', '2'),
(24, '09b8369032', '2', '1'),
(25, '7044c7a086', '1', '2'),
(26, '7044c7a086', '2', '1'),
(27, '7065f93e14', '1', '1'),
(28, '7065f93e14', '2', '2'),
(29, '70e57235fd', '1', '2'),
(30, '70e57235fd', '2', '1'),
(31, 'fd7a623a9d', '1', '1'),
(32, 'fd7a623a9d', '2', '2'),
(33, 'fd7a623a9d', '3', '2'),
(34, 'fd81353461', '1', '1'),
(35, 'fd81353461', '2', '2'),
(36, 'fd81353461', '3', '2'),
(37, 'fd8762b7c2', '1', '1'),
(38, 'fd8762b7c2', '2', '2'),
(39, 'fd8762b7c2', '3', '2'),
(40, 'fd8f011e8a', '1', '1'),
(41, 'fd8f011e8a', '2', '2'),
(42, 'fd8f011e8a', '3', '2'),
(43, 'fd9d60b084', '1', '1'),
(44, 'fd9d60b084', '2', '2'),
(45, 'fd9d60b084', '3', '2'),
(46, 'fda24d8327', '1', '1'),
(47, 'fda24d8327', '2', '2'),
(48, 'fda24d8327', '3', '2'),
(49, 'fda8203702', '1', '1'),
(50, 'fda8203702', '2', '2'),
(51, 'fda8203702', '3', '2'),
(52, 'fda8ca38e1', '1', '1'),
(53, 'fda8ca38e1', '2', '2'),
(54, 'fda8ca38e1', '3', '2'),
(55, 'fda97268c1', '1', '2'),
(56, 'fda97268c1', '2', '2'),
(57, 'fda97268c1', '3', '2'),
(58, 'fdb5f4f569', '1', '2'),
(59, 'fdb5f4f569', '2', '2'),
(60, 'fdb5f4f569', '3', '2'),
(61, 'fdbc31a522', '1', '2'),
(62, 'fdbc31a522', '2', '2'),
(63, 'fdbc31a522', '3', '2'),
(64, 'fdc85be575', '1', '2'),
(65, 'fdc85be575', '2', '2'),
(66, 'fdc85be575', '3', '2'),
(67, '0b4da6e344', '1', '1'),
(68, '0b4da6e344', '2', '2'),
(69, '0b4da6e344', '3', '2'),
(70, '0bb36c6c89', '1', '2'),
(71, '0bb36c6c89', '2', '1'),
(72, '0c00cd00d3', '1', '1'),
(73, '0c00cd00d3', '2', '2'),
(74, '0c00cd00d3', '3', '2'),
(75, '0c046278c6', '1', '1'),
(76, '0c046278c6', '2', '2'),
(77, '0c046278c6', '3', '2'),
(78, '0c0e4bf06b', '1', '2'),
(79, '0c0e4bf06b', '2', '2'),
(80, '0c0e4bf06b', '3', '2'),
(81, '0c140b726b', '1', '2'),
(82, '0c140b726b', '2', '2'),
(83, '0c140b726b', '3', '2'),
(84, '0f6e44804f', '1', '2'),
(85, '0f6e44804f', '2', '2'),
(86, '0f6e44804f', '3', '2'),
(87, '0f857cce9a', '1', '1'),
(88, '0f857cce9a', '2', '2'),
(89, '0f857cce9a', '3', '2'),
(90, '0ff41014f1', '1', '1'),
(91, '0ff41014f1', '2', '2'),
(92, '0ff41014f1', '3', '2'),
(93, '101f76e659', '1', '2'),
(94, '101f76e659', '2', '2'),
(95, '101f76e659', '3', '2'),
(96, '1026497b37', '1', '1'),
(97, '1026497b37', '2', '2'),
(98, '1026497b37', '3', '2'),
(99, '15df6d4a01', '1', '2'),
(100, '15df6d4a01', '2', '1'),
(101, '15e2329fa0', '1', '1'),
(102, '15e2329fa0', '2', '2'),
(103, '15e2329fa0', '3', '2'),
(104, '15e4e85639', '1', '1'),
(105, '15e4e85639', '2', '2'),
(106, '15e4e85639', '3', '2');



CREATE TABLE `adpost` (
  `id` int(99) NOT NULL,
  `adid` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `propertyid` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(99) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `adpost` (`id`, `adid`, `propertyid`, `value`) VALUES
(49, 'a98e7e97e2', '1', 'ad 1'),
(50, 'a98e7e97e2', '2', '0'),
(51, 'a98e7e97e2', '3', '120'),
(52, 'a98e7e97e2', '4', 'z'),
(53, 'ad129031b6', '1', 'teasss'),
(54, 'ad129031b6', '2', '1'),
(55, 'ad129031b6', '3', '120'),
(56, 'ad129031b6', '4', 'sdfr'),
(57, '0906c4d03d', '1', 'test 11111111'),
(58, '0906c4d03d', '2', '1'),
(59, '0906c4d03d', '3', '21'),
(60, '0906c4d03d', '4', 'asasassassa'),
(61, '09120c53c7', '1', 'MySql PDO not passing value from variable in php function'),
(62, '09120c53c7', '2', '1'),
(63, '09120c53c7', '3', '130'),
(64, '09120c53c7', '4', 'sdfghjklkmnbvftyhj'),
(65, '0955d0d4d2', '1', 'MySql PDO not passing value from variable in php function'),
(66, '0955d0d4d2', '2', '1'),
(67, '0955d0d4d2', '3', '130'),
(68, '0955d0d4d2', '4', 'fygvbhnj bkjhljkn,blhuijkn'),
(69, '09b8369032', '1', 'MySql PDO not passing value from variable in php function'),
(70, '09b8369032', '2', '0'),
(71, '09b8369032', '3', '133'),
(72, '09b8369032', '4', 'k;nkldfnsdkfndlkfndsnldsn'),
(73, '7044c7a086', '1', 'isset'),
(74, '7044c7a086', '2', '1'),
(75, '7044c7a086', '3', '123'),
(76, '7044c7a086', '4', 'qwdeqw'),
(77, '7065f93e14', '1', 'why do we use php()?'),
(78, '7065f93e14', '2', '1'),
(79, '7065f93e14', '3', '123'),
(80, '7065f93e14', '5', 'on'),
(81, '7065f93e14', '4', 'qweqweqw'),
(82, '70e57235fd', '1', 'why do we use bindparam()?'),
(83, '70e57235fd', '2', '1'),
(84, '70e57235fd', '3', '111'),
(85, '70e57235fd', '5', 'on'),
(86, '70e57235fd', '4', 'assasa'),
(87, 'fd7a623a9d', '1', 'IMAGE RESIXE'),
(88, 'fd7a623a9d', '2', '1'),
(89, 'fd7a623a9d', '3', 'NASN'),
(90, 'fd7a623a9d', '5', 'on'),
(91, 'fd7a623a9d', '4', 'SABIK'),
(92, 'fd81353461', '1', '11'),
(93, 'fd81353461', '2', '1'),
(94, 'fd81353461', '3', '1'),
(95, 'fd81353461', '5', 'on'),
(96, 'fd81353461', '4', '1111'),
(97, 'fd8762b7c2', '1', '11'),
(98, 'fd8762b7c2', '2', '1'),
(99, 'fd8762b7c2', '3', '1'),
(100, 'fd8762b7c2', '5', 'on'),
(101, 'fd8762b7c2', '4', '1111'),
(102, 'fd8f011e8a', '1', 'qq'),
(103, 'fd8f011e8a', '2', '0'),
(104, 'fd8f011e8a', '3', '11'),
(105, 'fd8f011e8a', '4', 'www'),
(106, 'fd9d60b084', '1', 'why do we use bindparam()?'),
(107, 'fd9d60b084', '2', '0'),
(108, 'fd9d60b084', '3', 'aaa'),
(109, 'fd9d60b084', '4', 's'),
(110, 'fda24d8327', '1', 'why do we use bindparam()?'),
(111, 'fda24d8327', '2', '0'),
(112, 'fda24d8327', '3', 'aaa'),
(113, 'fda24d8327', '4', 's'),
(114, 'fda8203702', '1', 'why do we use bindparam()?'),
(115, 'fda8203702', '2', '0'),
(116, 'fda8203702', '3', 'aaa'),
(117, 'fda8203702', '4', 's'),
(118, 'fda8ca38e1', '1', 'why do we use bindparam()?'),
(119, 'fda8ca38e1', '2', '0'),
(120, 'fda8ca38e1', '3', 'aaa'),
(121, 'fda8ca38e1', '4', 's'),
(122, 'fda97268c1', '1', ''),
(123, 'fda97268c1', '2', '0'),
(124, 'fda97268c1', '3', ''),
(125, 'fda97268c1', '4', ''),
(126, 'fdb5f4f569', '1', ''),
(127, 'fdb5f4f569', '2', '0'),
(128, 'fdb5f4f569', '3', ''),
(129, 'fdb5f4f569', '4', ''),
(130, 'fdbc31a522', '1', ''),
(131, 'fdbc31a522', '2', '0'),
(132, 'fdbc31a522', '3', ''),
(133, 'fdbc31a522', '4', ''),
(134, 'fdc85be575', '1', ''),
(135, 'fdc85be575', '2', '0'),
(136, 'fdc85be575', '3', 'aa'),
(137, 'fdc85be575', '4', ''),
(138, '0b4da6e344', '1', 'test'),
(139, '0b4da6e344', '2', '1'),
(140, '0b4da6e344', '3', '123'),
(141, '0b4da6e344', '5', 'on'),
(142, '0b4da6e344', '4', '12'),
(143, '0bb36c6c89', '1', 'MySql PDO not passing value from variable in php function'),
(144, '0bb36c6c89', '2', '1'),
(145, '0bb36c6c89', '3', '123'),
(146, '0bb36c6c89', '5', 'on'),
(147, '0bb36c6c89', '4', '123'),
(148, '0c00cd00d3', '1', 'aaa'),
(149, '0c00cd00d3', '2', '0'),
(150, '0c00cd00d3', '3', 'as'),
(151, '0c00cd00d3', '4', 'a'),
(152, '0c046278c6', '1', 'aaa'),
(153, '0c046278c6', '2', '0'),
(154, '0c046278c6', '3', 'a'),
(155, '0c046278c6', '4', 'a'),
(156, '0c0e4bf06b', '1', 'a'),
(157, '0c0e4bf06b', '2', '0'),
(158, '0c0e4bf06b', '3', 'a'),
(159, '0c0e4bf06b', '4', ''),
(160, '0c140b726b', '1', 'as'),
(161, '0c140b726b', '2', '0'),
(162, '0c140b726b', '3', '510'),
(163, '0c140b726b', '4', ''),
(164, '0f6e44804f', '1', 'a'),
(165, '0f6e44804f', '2', '1'),
(166, '0f6e44804f', '3', '1'),
(167, '0f6e44804f', '4', ''),
(168, '0f857cce9a', '1', 'q'),
(169, '0f857cce9a', '2', '0'),
(170, '0f857cce9a', '3', '123'),
(171, '0f857cce9a', '4', ''),
(172, '0ff41014f1', '1', '1'),
(173, '0ff41014f1', '2', '0'),
(174, '0ff41014f1', '3', '1'),
(175, '0ff41014f1', '4', ''),
(176, '101f76e659', '1', 'asdfg'),
(177, '101f76e659', '2', '0'),
(178, '101f76e659', '3', '1'),
(179, '101f76e659', '4', ''),
(180, '1026497b37', '1', '123'),
(181, '1026497b37', '2', '0'),
(182, '1026497b37', '3', '123'),
(183, '1026497b37', '4', ''),
(184, '15df6d4a01', '1', 'qwe'),
(185, '15df6d4a01', '2', '0'),
(186, '15df6d4a01', '3', '501'),
(187, '15df6d4a01', '4', ''),
(188, '15e2329fa0', '1', '123'),
(189, '15e2329fa0', '2', '0'),
(190, '15e2329fa0', '3', '123'),
(191, '15e2329fa0', '4', ''),
(192, '15e4e85639', '1', '123'),
(193, '15e4e85639', '2', '0'),
(194, '15e4e85639', '3', '123'),
(195, '15e4e85639', '4', '');


CREATE TABLE `adpostuser` (
  `id` int(99) NOT NULL,
  `adid` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `userid` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `posttime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `verif` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `adpostuser` (`id`, `adid`, `userid`, `posttime`, `verif`) VALUES
(1, 'a98e7e97e2', '1', '2019-08-31 21:57:27', '1'),
(2, 'ad129031b6', '1', '2019-09-01 01:57:29', '1'),
(3, '09b8369032', '1', '2019-09-17 14:38:27', '1'),
(4, '0906c4d03d', '2', '2019-09-18 00:44:53', '1'),
(5, '09120c53c7', '2', '2019-09-18 00:44:53', '1'),
(6, '7044c7a086', '1', '2019-10-04 14:35:24', '2'),
(7, '7065f93e14', '1', '2019-10-04 14:44:15', '2'),
(8, '70e57235fd', '1', '2019-10-04 15:18:15', '1'),
(9, 'fd7a623a9d', '1', '2019-11-04 13:47:50', '1'),
(10, 'fd81353461', '1', '2019-11-04 13:49:39', '1'),
(11, 'fd8762b7c2', '1', '2019-11-04 13:51:18', '1'),
(12, 'fd8f011e8a', '1', '2019-11-04 13:53:20', '1'),
(13, 'fd9d60b084', '1', '2019-11-04 13:57:10', '1'),
(14, 'fda1d5f5fd', '1', '2019-11-04 13:58:21', '1'),
(15, 'fda24d8327', '1', '2019-11-04 13:58:28', '1'),
(16, 'fda8203702', '1', '2019-11-04 14:00:02', '1'),
(17, 'fda8ca38e1', '1', '2019-11-04 14:00:12', '1'),
(18, 'fda97268c1', '1', '2019-11-04 14:00:23', '1'),
(19, 'fdb5f4f569', '1', '2019-11-04 14:03:43', '1'),
(20, 'fdbc31a522', '1', '2019-11-04 14:05:23', '1'),
(21, 'fdc85be575', '1', '2019-11-04 14:08:37', '1'),
(22, '0b4da6e344', '1', '2019-11-05 05:31:38', '1'),
(23, '0bb36c6c89', '1', '2019-11-05 05:58:46', '0'),
(24, '0c00cd00d3', '1', '2019-11-05 06:19:24', '0'),
(25, '0c046278c6', '1', '2019-11-05 06:20:22', '0'),
(26, '0c0e4bf06b', '1', '2019-11-05 06:23:00', '0'),
(27, '0c140b726b', '1', '2019-11-05 06:24:32', '0'),
(28, '0f6e44804f', '1', '2019-11-05 10:13:24', '0'),
(29, '0f857cce9a', '1', '2019-11-05 10:19:35', '0'),
(30, '0ff41014f1', '1', '2019-11-05 10:49:05', '0'),
(31, '101f76e659', '1', '2019-11-05 11:00:39', '0'),
(32, '1026497b37', '1', '2019-11-05 11:02:28', '0'),
(33, '15df6d4a01', '1', '2019-11-05 17:33:10', '0'),
(34, '15e2329fa0', '1', '2019-11-05 17:33:55', '0'),
(35, '15e4e85639', '1', '2019-11-05 17:34:38', '0');


CREATE TABLE `adproperty` (
  `id` int(99) NOT NULL,
  `property` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `property2` varchar(99) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `adproperty` (`id`, `property`, `property2`) VALUES
(1, 'Title', 'title'),
(2, 'Type of Ad', 'typeofad'),
(3, 'Price', 'price'),
(4, 'Description', 'description'),
(5, 'Negotiable', 'negotiable');





CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `stid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `mob` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(999) NOT NULL,
  `uni` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `uniid` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(999) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `fb` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `twitter` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `linkedin` varchar(999) NOT NULL,
  `about` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `pro_pic` varchar(99) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default.png',
  `tespass` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `membersince` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `student` (`stid`, `fname`, `lname`, `gender`, `email`, `mob`, `address`, `uni`, `uniid`, `password`, `city`, `fb`, `twitter`, `linkedin`, `about`, `pro_pic`, `tespass`, `code`, `membersince`) VALUES
(1, 'aa111111ssssssss', '222ss', '', '1@h.com', '18226239935', 'cox bazafrhhh', '2', '1', '8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92', '', '', '', 'linkedin.com/1.h', '', 'default.png', '1', 'ahWHvPmIJnpw', '2019-09-15 03:09:51'),
(2, 'sabik', 'sabik', '', 'sab@gmai.com', '65789', '6789', '1', '', '6e7d04d2b700028a8f47464737a6257f9652f277e26ebe6c532f01d40f6ac8c8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '2019-09-15 03:09:51'),
(3, 'sabikasdasd', 'qwerty', '', 'w@w.comaaza', '1', 'q2w23', '1', 'qwe', '8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92', 'sss', 'aaa', 'lk', '', 'sssaaqaaaaqw', 'default.png', '0', '', '2019-09-15 03:09:51'),
(4, 'sabik', 'sabik', '', 'b@gmail.com', '3456789', '567890', '1', '89', 'cd70bea023f752a0564abb6ed08d42c1440f2e33e29914e55e0be1595e24f45a', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '2019-09-15 03:09:51'),
(5, 'sabik', 'sabik', '', 'b2@gmail.com', '3456789', '567890', '1', '89', '8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '2019-09-15 03:09:51'),
(6, 'sbaik', 'sanioasndoas', '', 'nasnd@gmail.com', 'knasldn', 'lkjsndflkndsa', '1', '123123123', '66e2beec7e35b80fc9a2c46d41caa10c63632ed1d76e31e731fc9a34cee7c566', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '2019-09-15 03:09:51'),
(7, 'Taeef', 'Najib', '', 'taeefnajib@gmail.com', '001937', 'defghjkl;', '2', '123456789', '8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'ahWHvPmIJnpw', '2019-09-15 03:09:51'),
(8, 'asif', 'imtiaz', 'm', 'asif@ghoorni.com', '01685726653', '', '1', '15126626', 'f0eee373417d6cee2d80f67483132ab44369c0ff115015a39745feba9dc736ac', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', 'zTqbNEgmZCa7', '2019-11-05 05:16:30');



CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `stid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `mob` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(999) NOT NULL,
  `uni` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `uniid` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(999) NOT NULL,
  `verif` varchar(99) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `uni` (
  `id` int(99) NOT NULL,
  `uniname` varchar(999) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `uni` (`id`, `uniname`) VALUES
(1, 'Ahsanullah University of Science and Technology'),
(2, 'NSU');
```

FIDDLE LINK :
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5YKoERT5fwZ5dwCoVQPWbi/0#&togetherjs=Jaq8cRqBti

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please re-read the linked answer

Comment: added db fiddle link

Comment: Better, but unfortunately, it's not 'minimal' - the 'm' in 'mcre'!

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with the main query along with the minimal sql query

Comment: Store data using the correct data type for that data!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `OR`, I didn't realized that this will work in `mysql`, if you try to run this query in `postgres or mssql`, it will fail.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) as `num`    
FROM product a 
INNER JOIN customer b ON a.userid=b.cid 
INNER JOIN productcategory c ON a.id=c.id 
INNER JOIN productpost d ON a.adid=d.adid 
WHERE a.verif=1 AND c.cattype=1 AND (d.value LIKE '%a%') 
    AND (d.propertyid in (1,4) OR (d.propertyid=3 AND d.value BETWEEN 0 AND 50))
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ieKXeXEssHsjufXxmo3jww/1#&togetherjs=7Mhx6G5UqI)

Comment: But OR in here "(d.propertyid in (1,4) OR (d.propertyid=3 AND d.value BETWEEN 0 AND 50))" means that either of the statement being true query will progress but what I want is that filter the "adid" in LIKE being found in value column in propertyid 1 and 4  and then again filter the "adid" again where value is between 0 and 50 in propertyid 3.

Comment: If I give an example it would be that if there are 4 "adid" and 3 of them has LIKE '%a%' in value in propertyid 1 and 4, and among those three, 2 of them has value 0 to 50 in propertid 3, so in first condition it filter out three and in the next condition it filters value between 0 to 50 and at the end shows two "adid".

Comment: Just tweak the end of this answer to be `... AND ((d.value LIKE '%a%' AND d.propertyid IN (1,4)) OR (d.propertyid=3 AND d.value BETWEEN 0 AND 50))`

Comment: It does not work. Your query will do is that either search in property 3 or 4 OR 0 to 50 in property 3, but i want it so that first it will filter the result from property 3 or 4 and then among the filtered result will filter again with 0 to 50 in property 3

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT '23' BETWEEN '220' AND '240';
+------------------------------+
| '23' BETWEEN '220' AND '240' |
+------------------------------+
|                            1 |
+------------------------------+
```

Can you see what's wrong here?

Comment: this is which part?